# Selenium RSpec2 crash doing ActiveRecord Queries on Rails 3

Tags: testing, selenium, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

I am having a very difficult time trying to get my tests working correctly.

If ever I have :js => true (Selenium and Mozilla) and do any sort of ActiveRecord query directly on a model I have big issues.

For example this expect block doesn't work.

```
pending 'displays flash error when another User contains email' do 
  user = User.create!(:email => email)
  expect {
    fill_in 'Email', :with => user.email
    fill_in 'Password', :with => password
    fill_in 'Re-enter', :with => password
    check 'agree'
    click_button 'Sign up'
  }.to_not change(User, :count)
  current_path.should eq(new_user_registration_path)
  page.should have_content("Password doesn't match confirmation")
end
```

Any time I have something like

```
user = User.last
user.update_attributes(:agreement => nil)
```

It either just ignores the code, crashes the test, redirects me to the sign in page, or some other spontaneous behavior.  It doesn't seem to be consistent.  I have even had some MYSQL time outs.

Has anyone else had similar problems or know how to fix it?